# Does JavaFX have a future?

Tags: java, ria, javafx

I have not intended to hash and rehash the same matter, but just to decide, what to learn first (JavaFX, Flex, HTML5, etc.) I would pull through a kind of survey, especially as the recent similar questions here came out since at least one year.

So, what is JavaFX prospect as a [RIA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Internet_Application) technology for the next couple of years?

Comment: HTML(5) is a standard, so I'd go with it...

Comment: No offense, but JavaFX does not have a very bright future. Go for HTML 5

Comment: I would learn html 5 + JavaScript (probably a popular framework such as JQuery) for RIA technology.

Comment: Albert, I'm sorry your question got migrated here unnecessarily, but we don't accept questions that are attempting to poll the community members or predict the future of a technology.

Comment: Here's a good (IMO) indicator: http://www.google.com/trends?q=html5%2Cjavafx

Answer (score 6):

I would learn HTML5 because it is the standard way of doing things. Lets say you have 100 hours to spend learning any of the technologies you mention in your question. If you spend 100 hours learning JavaFX and 2 years from now JavaFX is dead then your knowledge of JavaFX is useless. If you spend 100 hours learning HTML5 then 2 years from now when HTML5 is even more available than it is today your 100 hour effort is still relevant.

Learn HTML5 and if you can't do something you need in it then look at alternatives.

Comment: There are probably some reasons, that were crucial for your choice.

Comment: That's a pretty convoluted way of saying "I believe Java FX does not have a future and HTML 5 does".

Answer (score 4):

JavaFX is definitely not a mainstream technology now, but it might help you to understand how non-HTML and JS-based RIA applications work. So, if you just decide what to start learning I would suggest first trying to get acquainted with some general ideas of how implementing [RIA applications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Internet_application) and every RIA technology would do here as long as you have good materials for them.

On a long run I would favor a platform and vendor agnostic approaches, like HTML5. Nonetheless, looking to some established RIA technologies, like [Flash](http://www.adobe.com/de/products/flash.html) from Macromedia/Adobe, [Silverlight](http://www.silverlight.net/) from MS or [Google Web Toolkit](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/) is never a disadvantage -- they definitely have some brilliant ideas you might not find elsewhere.